# Tabulation added to commands and downloaded file beginning

Tags: command-line, magento2.3.5-p1, command

I don't know when it started happening so I don't know where to look.
For example if I run a command it shows like

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
    Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
```

It should have that tabulation, in files it does the same, for example if I download a picture it adds that space too so it's impossible to open unless we remove that space with some text editor.

After searching for a solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/22132/86398.
The problem is that I don't know what files should I look into, so I wanted to know if there is any way I could run a command that could check if that case exists in any file.
Or if I should look for something else that could do this.

Thanks in advance!